# Package is missing dependencies for libraries - OpenWRT

Tags: dependencies, package, libraries, dependency-management, openwrt

I am trying to compile OpenWRT with a custom package I have made inside it. Here is the **OpenWRT** Makefile for my package:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2008 OpenWrt.org
#
# This is free software, licensed under the GNU General Public License v2.
# See /LICENSE for more information.
#
# $Id$

include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=amld
PKG_RELEASE:=1

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/amld
 SECTION:=utils
 CATEGORY:=Utilities
 TITLE:=amld -- prints a snarky message  
 DEPENDS:=+libssl +libcrypto +librt
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

define Build/Configure
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)
endef

define Package/amld/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/amld $(1)/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,amld))
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
Package amld is missing dependencies for the following libraries:
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
librt.so.0
libssl.so.1.0.0
```

I am unsure of what to add, does anybody have any ideas? Thanks

**Edit**

Here is my Makefile for my package:

```
LDFLAGS=-lssl -lcrypto -lrt
CFLAGS=-g -I /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

all: amlpkcs12 amld

amlpkcs12:amlpkcs12.o
    $(CC) amlpkcs12.o -g -o amlpkcs12 $(LDFLAGS)

amld: amld.o iot.o bridge.o sysconf.o
    $(CC) bridge.o iot.o amld.o sysconf.o -g -o amld $(LDFLAGS)

amlpkcs12.o: amlpkcs12.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c  amlpkcs12.c

amld.o: amld.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -g -DVERSION=\"1.0\" amld.c

sysconf.o: sysconf.c sysconf.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c sysconf.c

bridge.o:bridge.c bridge.h iot.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c bridge.c

iot.o: iot.c iot.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -g iot.c

clean:
    rm *.o amlpkcs12 amld
```

**Update**

Also see my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190030/openwrt-package-missing-dependencies-when-recompiling) if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Why do you need this `-I /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`? AFAIK you should use only the headers provided by OpenWrt.

Comment: Try `DEPENDS:=+libopenssl`, like **openssh** package does.

Comment: Tried that @yegorich, no luck :[

Comment: Have you tried to use [CMake](http://cmake.org/) instead of simple Makefile? Here is an [example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Examples#Set_Link_Directories) on how to find OpenSSL. You'll need to add `include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/cmake.mk` to your package/Makefile. I have a project, that has about 4 external dependencies like cjson, uci, zlog etc. and I have no problems.

Comment: Looks like removing the -lrt flags and the empty define build/configure might have done it

Comment: You're right, that makes sense. Could you answer your own question with proper Makefiles? So that other devs could use this info?

Comment: Sure, might even earn some of my bounty back xD

Comment: Nope that didn't do it, had it working very briefly, pretty sure I didn't change the Makefile. Back to square one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally got it, had to add change

`$(eval $(call BuildPackage,amld))`

to

`$(eval $(call BuildPackage,amld,+libopenssl))`

Full Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=amld
PKG_RELEASE:=1

TARGET_LDFLAGS+=/usr/include/openssl
PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=libopenssl

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/amld
 SECTION:=utils
 DEPENDS:=+libopenssl
 CATEGORY:=Utilities
 TITLE:=amld -- AccessMyLan Daemon
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./files/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)
endef

define Package/amld/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/amld $(1)/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,amld,+libopenssl))
```

Comment: *N.B*: the important change here was using the correct library name. It should be `libopenssl` not `libssl` and `libcrypto`. Putting the dependency in the eval BuildPackage call or in the define Package/amld block would both have worked if the correct name had been used.

Answer (score 1):

Please check `OpenWRT\tmp\.config-package.in` . This has the dependency tree generated as soon as build starts. It can give some hints

Comment: there's no such file on my machine

Answer (score 0):

If you recompiled a package that produces a new lib that's not being installed in build_dir/root-xyz, and that lib is now needed by another package (for example you rebuilt gcc and enabled libasan.so, so now packages that require libasan.so will complain), you can fix things up manually:

- copy the new libs manually into build_dir
- add the new libs to the generated provides file (e.g. libc.provides)
- re-run make for that package